# Is it possible to use simulated (bootstrap) A/A tests of historic data to estimate the impact of confounding factors on the treatment effect?

Tags: inference, experiment-design, simulation, causality, treatment-effect

I recently heard a proposal for a method to measure the degree to which confounding variables impact historic results of A/B tests.

In order to ascertain the degree to which confounding has impacted the accuracy of previous A/B test results using a t-test, it was proposed that we historic data could be used to run simulated A/A tests by repeatedly:

1. sampling the treatment group with replacement
2. Calculate the difference in conversions between the bootstrapped sample and the overall treatment group sample

And use these differences as a way to measure the 'variance due to confounding factors'.

From my understanding, this does not make sense as randomly sampling the treatment group this way will only provide information about the inherent variability of treatment conversion rates due to random sampling (i.e., information regarding the variance of the sampling distribution of conversion rates).

This process says nothing about any inherent bias that exists within the treatment group due to confounding as the systematic bias will be masked by the random sampling because the central limit theorem determines the differences between 2 random samples from the same population will approximate 0, and doing this repeatedly certainly tell us nothing about the control group.

I.e., confounding is a bias in measurement and not variability in measurement.

I have further illustrated my point with python code  below.

Question: Is it possible to use simulated (bootstrap resampling) A/A tests to estimate the degree to which confounding affects treatment effect measurement? Or am I missing something here?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

n = 10000
x = np.random.normal(.4, 0.06, n)  # Propensity to convert
confounding = np.clip(np.random.logistic(2 * x, scale = 0,size = n),0,1) #create confounding with x
#epsilon = np.random.normal(0.00, 0.5, n) 
t = np.random.binomial(1, confounding, n)  # Treatment group indicator

# Calculate conversion probability using x & t and ensure p stays within [0, 1]
p = np.clip(x + t * 0.05 , 0, 1)  # Conversion probability (assume uniform treatment effect)
conv = np.random.binomial(1, p, n)  # Actual conversions

df = pd.DataFrame({'t': t, 'x': x,'conv': conv})
treated = df.query('t == 1')

diffs = []
p1 = treated['conv'].mean()

for _ in range(1000):
    sample = treated.sample(1000, replace=True)
    p2 = sample['conv'].mean()
    diffs.append(p1 - p2)

np.mean(diffs), np.std(diffs)  # This will not directly reflect the variance of confounding

#bias when not controlling for confounder
reg_unadj = smf.logit("conv ~ t", data=df).fit()
print(reg_unadj.summary())
perc_unadj = np.exp(reg_unadj.params[0] + reg_unadj.params[1])/(1 + np.exp(reg_unadj.params[0] + reg_unadj.params[1]))
print('bias = ', .05 - perc_unadj)

#bias when controlling for confounder
reg_adj = smf.logit("conv ~ t + x", data=df).fit()
print(reg_adj.summary())
perc_adj = np.exp(reg_adj.params[0] + reg_adj.params[1])/(1 + np.exp(reg_adj.params[0] + reg_adj.params[1]))
print('bias = ', .05 - perc_adj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of the burden of proof, I'm not sure the best way is to argue why this wouldn't work. So perhaps the real question is: **Is there any reason to believe this might work?**

To make that question more concrete, how should bootstrapping be able to distinguish confounding from any inherent stochasticity in the relationship?
For intervention $X$, outcome $Y$, noise $\varepsilon$ and some functional dependency $f(\cdot)$ with $Y := f(X) + \varepsilon$, the bootstrapping procedure would differ depending on $\varepsilon$ even in the absence of any confounding. So I don't really see how this approach could work.

A tool that might be useful for you is [this type of causal sensitivity analysis](https://carloscinelli.com/files/Cinelli%20et%20al%20(2020)%20-%20sensemakr.pdf). It doesn't give you the strength of confounding, but it provides an answer to how strong confounding would have to be to obscure the true relationship - then you'll have to decide if there could have plausibly been confounding of that strength.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you expand on what you mean by ‘the bootstrapping procedure would differ depending on epsilon even in the absence of confounding’ please?

Comment: Imagine there is no confounding and the causal effect is the same linear $\beta$ for every observation. If $\varepsilon = 0$, the bootstrapping samples (and if fact every single observation) will all give the same result. If $\varepsilon$ is something else, they will differ, and the more so the bigger $\varepsilon$. You could just try that out in a simulation if you wanted.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think you are saying that, even in the absence of any confounding, the bootstrapping procedure will produce different results by changing the amount of random variation - therefore, even if it was possible to capture 'variance due to confounding', there is no way to separate changes in the results due to 'confounding variance' and inherent stochasticity?

Comment: Exactly, and that's just one problem that occurred to me, there may be others (e.g. what if effects are nonlinear?). To do this in a principled way you'd have to ask the other way round: How and under what conditions would this approach work? I think ultimately the idea seems to be that variation in treatment effects might be due to confounding, which could be interesting but it does require justification.

Comment: Yeah I think there are a number of problems really. It's interesting that you point out it might be better to frame a question as under what conditions will this work rather than going straight for why it won't work...thanks man, interesting link as well.